# Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0 inside a Java Class

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, google-api-client

I have created a GoogleMap inside a java class so I can reuse it multiple times without repeating code.

I currently have two maps on the same fragment. One map, is for the user to select a collection location (Item picked up from). The second map is for a delivery location (Item is going to). Both of my maps work, however, the second map on the page crashed when I try and add the line:

**Inside Fragment, PostAJobFragment**

```
// editTextSearch is an AutoCompleteTextView
map2.setEditSearchAPIListener(editTextSearch2, getActivity());
```

I have created a map instance and accessed the method setEditSearchAPIListener in my Java Class. Which is as follows:

**Inside Java Class, Map**

```
public GoogleApiClient setEditSearchAPIListener(AutoCompleteTextView editTextSearch, FragmentActivity fragmentActivity)
    {
        mGoogleApiClient1 = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(fragmentActivity)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(fragmentActivity, this)
                .build();

        editTextSearch.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteItemClickListener);
        placeAutocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(fragmentActivity, mGoogleApiClient1, LAT_LNG_BOUNDS, null);
        editTextSearch.setAdapter(placeAutocompleteAdapter);

        return mGoogleApiClient1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGoogleApiClient1.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
        mGoogleApiClient1.disconnect();
    }
```

I get an error saying `'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0'`

I have lookeed over other answers which say to use an onPause method. As my Map uses a Java class and not a fragment it doesnt appear to work. 
Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue. When creating the GoogleApiClient I trying to create it in the Java Class In a method called setGoogleApiClient. It would successfully run once but the second time it would crash.

I put the code in the onCreateView method in my previous fragment and it works fine.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_an_advert, container, false);
        layoutView = view;

        // Collection Map
        map1 = new Map();
        map2 = new Map();
        getViewsByIds(view);

        // Create google api client, so user has pre-set options to select.
        /*
      The main entry point for Google Play services integration
     */
       mGoogleApiClient1 = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), 0, this)
                .build();

        PlaceAutocompleteAdapter placeAutocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), mGoogleApiClient1, LAT_LNG_BOUNDS, null);
        map1.setPlaceAutocompleteAdapter(placeAutocompleteAdapter);
        map1.setmGoogleApiClient1(mGoogleApiClient1);

        map2.setPlaceAutocompleteAdapter(placeAutocompleteAdapter);
        map2.setmGoogleApiClient1(mGoogleApiClient1);

        editTextSearch.setOnItemClickListener(map1.mAutocompleteItemClickListener);
        editTextSearch2.setOnItemClickListener(map2.mAutocompleteItemClickListener);

        editTextSearch.setAdapter(placeAutocompleteAdapter);
        editTextSearch2.setAdapter(placeAutocompleteAdapter);
```